# Angularjs jquery binding between states

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Let's say I have two states:

```
.state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/page1.html',
    controller: 'page1'
})

.state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    templateUrl: 'pages/templates/page2.html',
    controller: 'page2'
})
```

They both have the element `<div id="clickme'>DO IT</div>`.

---

In one controller I have:

```
$("body").on('click', '#clickme', function(e) { alert("clicked"); });
```

But not on the other controller.

What is the most effective way to *restart* my bindings if I have a lot of these separately going on within my different controllers?

I don't want them to be active when I switch state's because some things may overlap or just want to make sure nothing overlaps.

Comment: In the Angular way you should not do DOM manipulation in the controller, But to your question when a new state is loaded, the old template will be removed and the new one loaded.

Comment: There are very few cases you should be using jQuery with angular.  For example if you want to listen to a button click event, you'd use ng-click on the element, and have a function on your scope in the controller that is called on click.  No jQuery required.

Comment: ah okay, I will do that then. sorry, I am new to angular @DanielGimenez.

Comment: Must read:[thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most efficient way is not to do it at all. As the comments have pointed out, you probably shouldn't be using jQuery in your Angular code. [Its just not the Angular way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background).

What you probably want is some [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
.state('page1', {
    url: '/page1',
    template: '<page1>',
    controller: 'page1'
})

.state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    template: '<page2>',
    controller: 'page2'
})
```

And then in your directive code you will have something like

```
.directive('page1', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div ng-click="doIt()">DO IT</div>',
    link: function($scope){
      $scope.doIt = function(){...}
    }
  };
});
```